# How much data can store in flutter_secure_storage?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How much data can store in flutter_secure_storage ?
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage#-readme-tab-
is that possible to store 10mb of data in flutter_secure_storage?

Comment: Why don't you try storing it? No space limitation is mentioned. And logically it should depend upon the free space of your device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flutter_secure_storage is storing data in shared preference but with encryption in android so it can store data that shared preference can store